# Spring MVC Rest Service JSON - Setting default value for boolean as true

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Setting default value for `boolean` as `true`

This is the dto clas which is having boolean value in it.

**DTO class**

```
public class SensitivityDto extends AuditableEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private long sensitivityId;
    @JsonIgnore
    private boolean isSelected;

    public SensitivityDto() {
    }
    /** other getter/setters */
    public boolean isIsSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setIsSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

}
```

**input json**

```
{
  "sensitivity": {
    "sensitivityId": 100,
    "isSelected": "true", // if not passing this field always its treated as null.

  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public @ResponseBody ResultDecorator saveLabResultCultureDetails(@RequestBody SensitivityDto sensitivityDto) throws  Exception {

}
```

How can I set boolean value default to true, ***So that if this value is not present in json, then it should not be false it should be true.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about?

```
@JsonIgnore
private boolean isSelected = true;
```

**From the comment:**

> then even I'm sending false in json, its takng as true

You have to remove `@JsonIgnore` and use [@JsonAutoDetect](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect.html), as follows:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;

@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public class SensitivityDto extends AuditableEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long sensitivityId;


    private boolean isSelected = true;

    public SensitivityDto() {
    }

    /** other getter/setters */
    public boolean isIsSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setIsSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

}
```

Comment: then even I'm sending false in json, its takng as true

Comment: Why did you add the @JsonIgnore annotation if you don't want to ignore it?

Comment: Response I don't need that. So added. I required that in request.

Comment: Then remove the `@JsonIgnore` and use a `@JsonView` for your response, where that field is excluded in the response. With `@JsonIgnore` you can't distinguish between request and response, it will always be ignored in JSON serialization or deserialization.